# Sonarqube container on Azure WebApp and SQLAzure

Tags: azure, docker, sonarqube, containers

I try to install sonarqube container on an Azure WebApp.
 
It works fine as long as you use the H2 database. Unfortunately, this database is emptied each time the container restarts.
Therefore, i'm trying to use SQLServer instead of H2.
Everything works fine when the container is hosted on my machine. But on the WebApp, i get an issue form the underlying ElasticSearch:
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
I'm not a Linux power user, but as far as i could read, it can only be changed on the host machine which i cannot tweak.
I've tried to use different containers such as this one:
 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/templates/101-webapp-linux-sonarqube-azuresql/ 
I've alsofollowed this tutorial:
https://www.natmarchand.fr/sonarqube-azure-webapp-containers/ 
Nothing works :( 
Has anyone succeeded to install a Sonarqube container on Azure with SQL Server as database? Or has anyone solved the issue mentioned above?
Thanks a lot for your feedbacks.

Comment: I believe this article meets your needs: https://medium.com/rowden/the-unexpected-journey-of-deploying-a-sonarqube-azure-app-service-effdf1484c62

Comment: did you tried to deploy SQL Server on different container and Sonarqube on another and then connect them! The issue is simple a normal container cannot able to host. Container needs more space :)

Comment: In fact it seems the issue is due to a validation made by elastic search, which is not made when using the internal H2 database (it can be tried with an official container). The article mentionned by gcleite seems promising but i have to dig a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to set that parameter using configuration application settings, no need to create a new container.

In the portal go to application settings and add a new application setting. The name will be SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE and the value will be true. This passes the variable to the container and allows it start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I set it this way, but forgot to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I was able to solve. There is an environment variable in SonarQube code:

```
-Dsonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable
```

If set to `true` will not force the bootstrap checks.

We cannot set this env variable from Azure App Service since Azure will replace `.` to `-`.

So, the only way to make it work is to use custom docker image and pass the param `-Dsonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable` in the custom run script.

If you need more details, please check out my page here: https://shubhamgargcth.github.io/SonarQubeAzureAppService/

Comment: Hi,thanks for your feedback. I'll check this week end if it works

Comment: This can be used by setting the startup command on Azure App Service to `-Dsonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable=true`. There is no need for custom script.

Comment: Thank you @RuiLopes, this works fine as for 8.X versions.

Answer (score 1):

As an addon to Shubham Garg's answer:

According to [SonarQube 7.8 release upgrade notes](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.8/setup/upgrade-notes/), the checks is enforced on this version. Therefore, the latest version that will work on App Service without any modification is **`7.7`**.

> **Elasticsearch bootstrap checks enforced**
>
> SonarQube will now fail to start if Elasticsearch's bootstrap checks fail. That means you may need to [adjust the maximum number of open files and processes](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.8/requirements/requirements/) for the SonarQube user as part of this upgrade ([SONAR-11264](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/SONAR-11264)).

---

As mentioned by Rui Lopes, that `-Dsonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable=true` can be added to startup command of the Azure App Service for version 8 and newer.

[image: App Service Configuration]

But to get the version `7.8` to `7.9.6` working on Azure App Service is to build your own image with `sonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable` set to `true`.

These are the step-by-step instruction to build your own custom image from the [official source](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube):

1. Clone the official SonarQube Docker repository: [`SonarSource/docker-sonarqube`](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube)

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube
   ```
2. Check out the tag of the version you want to build (example: `7.9.6`)

   ```bash
   git checkout 7.9.6
   ```
3. Navigate to the directory containing the your desired edition and version. (example: `7.9.6 Community`)

   ```bash
   cd 7/community
   ```
4. Add the `sq_opts+=("-Dsonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable=true")` to the `run.sh` file just below this block:

   ```bash
   while IFS='=' read -r envvar_key envvar_value
   do
       if [[ "$envvar_key" =~ sonar.* ]] || [[ "$envvar_key" =~ ldap.* ]]; then
           sq_opts+=("-D${envvar_key}=${envvar_value}")
       fi
   done < <(env)

   # <- Add here
   ```

   Notes: this block also look similar in `/8/community/setup.sh` and `/9/community/setup.sh` but with an indentation (preserve the indentation when adding the new line).

   The mentioned portion of the file should look like this:

   ```bash
   # The upper part is omitted

   while IFS='=' read -r envvar_key envvar_value
   do
       if [[ "$envvar_key" =~ sonar.* ]] || [[ "$envvar_key" =~ ldap.* ]]; then
           sq_opts+=("-D${envvar_key}=${envvar_value}")
       fi
   done < <(env)

   sq_opts+=("-Dsonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable=true") # <- Added line

   exec tail -F ./logs/es.log & # this tail on the elasticsearch logs is a temporary workaround, see https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/6361#issuecomment-516184762
   exec java -jar lib/sonar-application-$SONAR_VERSION.jar \
   -Dsonar.log.console=true \
   -Dsonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts="$SONARQUBE_WEB_JVM_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom" \
   "${sq_opts[@]}" \
   "$@"
   ```

   Save the file and proceed to the next step.
5. Build and push the image as usual

   ```bash
   docker build -t phwt/sonarqube-app-service:7.9.6-community .
   docker push phwt/sonarqube-app-service:7.9.6-community
   ```
6. Change the configuration in your App Service to point to the new image and proceed with the setup/upgrade.

---

You can check out the images I've modified and built for version `7.9.6-community`, `8.9.9-community` (LTS), and `9.7.0-community` here: [phwt/sonarqube-app-service](https://hub.docker.com/r/phwt/sonarqube-app-service).

But it's best to build the image by yourself just to make sure that the image you are using is only modified by **you** from the **official source**.

Answer (score -1):

```
    ulimits:
      nofile:
       soft: 65536
       hard: 65536
```

is your friend.

This example seems to be the exact fit for your case:
https://github.com/MrZoidberg/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes/docker-compose-postgres-example.yml

Comment: Hello,have you successfully implement the solution above? It uses PostGre in a container. I want to use SqlAzure to store SQ data. I've tried with ulimits but it does not change anything. The issue is unfortunatly still present.

Answer (score -1):

I tried `SonarQube` in my team and deployed on `Azure` with `SqlServer` in a linux VM.

That was simple

These are 2 articles which can help you step by step, how to deploy Sonarqube on azure.

https://tariqabubaker.wordpress.com/2017/07/31/step-by-step-how-create-sonarqube-vm-using-ms-azure-and-configure-it-to-be-integrated-with-vsts/

https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/sonarqube-arm/

PS: My `SQLServer` was running outside of `SonarQube` container/VM I deployed SQL Server and create one DB and then connect DB with `SonarQube` config.

Comment: Hello,thanks for the feedback, but the question was about a PaaS deployment. Regards